# How to make Angular application read cookies at start up

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an `Angular` application which on start up should read `Cookies` (`app.component.ts`) and should redirect to a new component passing the read values. How can I do this?

Currently, my server provides the required values as html tag attributes to `<app-root>` (eg `<app-root something="someValue">`) and the `AppComponent` reads the attributes using `this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute("somethings")`. Though it works, I'll prefer to read the values from `Cookies` or from say an `HTTP Header`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be happy to accept other answers but the research so far hints that what I am trying to do can't be done. Quoting a response from ([Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)), `Unfortunately, there isn't an API to give you the HTTP response headers for your initial page request.`. So what I am doing at the moment is probably one of the possible work arounds 
1) I can set html attributes. If I am concerned about security, I can make them `hidden` - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp
2) I can set cookies in the response and get the cookies using plain javascript (document.cookies). https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp and [What is the equivalent to AngularJS's ngcookie in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772529/what-is-the-equivalent-to-angularjss-ngcookie-in-angular-6)